# Taylor Polynomials question

Tags: taylor-expansion

Use Taylor polynomials at $x=x_0$ to approximate $\sqrt8$.

I don't understand the point of Taylor polynomials here. If $T^{(0)}=f(x_0)=\sqrt8$, then what is the point of doing subsequent Taylor polynomials? Why do we need to use Taylor polynomials to approximate the function at some value, if $T^{(0)}$ gives us this value?

Comment: How do you think your calculator/computer gives you decimals for $\sqrt{8}$?

Comment: I think I am understanding something incorrectly. If we take $f(x_0)=\sqrt(8)$, doesn't this five us the full number including all decimals? Why are subsequent polynomial terms necessary?

Comment: The approximation should be doable without a calculator and by hand (though a bit tedious). Also, pretend that your calculator doesn't know how to give $\sqrt{8}$. Use the Taylor polynomial and some nice close value to get an approximation.

Comment: Would I need to take the function f(x)=$\sqrt x$, or some simpler one? I don't think I understand how to choose functions for this case.

Comment: You need to use $\sqrt{x}$. It is the choice of $a$ to center your Taylor polynomial at that will make life more or less difficult.

Comment: So $x_0$ cannot be = 9.2?

Comment: It could be if you wanted it to though since you are going to have to take $\sqrt{x_0}$ you should probably pick something you can actually take the square root of.

Comment: Ok, so the goal is to pick a function of which we can directly take a square root and use that to approximate a more difficult expression?

Comment: @JohnHabert, it doesn't use this method at all :-)

Comment: @vonbrand Depends on the underlying hardware/software. I've seen code that uses Taylor polynomials before though it is on the older side now. Cheap computing power means other methods are easier to implement and just as fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving to an answer to give a little more detail. Ignoring choice of $x_0$ (or $a$ as I referred to it in comments), you can find the derivatives of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ fairly easily using the Power Rule. We know that we can create an $n$th degree polynomial approximation $P_n(x)$ using the formula $\displaystyle P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k$. The key to the approximation is to choose a good value for $x_0$ so that (a) you can do the calculations easily and (b) you minimize the number of terms needed to get an acceptable error. Since we want to approximate $\sqrt{8}$, a good choice would be $x_0=9$. No mention of needed error is mentioned so let's try using $n=2$ as a first approximation.

$f(9) = 3 \\
f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \Longrightarrow f'(9) = \dfrac{1}{6} \\
f''(x) = \dfrac{-1}{4x^{\frac{3}{2}}} \Longrightarrow f''(9) = \dfrac{-1}{108}$

So we have $P_2(x) = 3 + \dfrac{1}{6}(x-9) - \dfrac{1}{216}(x-9)^2$. This gives an approximation for $\sqrt{8}$ of $P_2(8) = 3 + \dfrac{1}{6}(8-9) - \dfrac{1}{216}(8-9)^2 = \dfrac{611}{216} \approx 2.8287$.

Answer (score 0):

You want the value of $\sqrt{8}$, by starting from a known square root. A nearby value is $\sqrt{9}=3$. So you want an expansion of the form:
$$
\sqrt{9-x} = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2+\ldots
$$
Here you know $a_0 =3$, and you want to stop adding terms when you've got enough precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the fact (if not, to get an approximation you may compute the first derivatives "by hand") that $$\sqrt{1 + x} = \sum \limits_{i = 0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{i} x^i$$ for $|x| < 1$, then we have $$\sqrt 8 = \sqrt{9 - 1} = \sqrt{9(1 - \frac{1}{9})} = 3\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{9}} = 3\sum \limits_{i = 0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{i}(-\frac{1}{9})^i$$